# Trouble with flexbox in Polymer

Tags: html, polymer, flexbox

I must say that I am constantly struggling trying to understand flex and I have a specific issue I have been strugglign with in Polymer, now boiled down to a bare minimum. I have something that looks like this:

```
<body fullbleed unresolved layout vertical>
    <div>
        <div vertical layout>
            <core-toolbar>
                <div>Help Me</div>
            </core-toolbar>
            <div horizontal layout>
                <div vertical layout flex>
                    <div style="background-color:red">
                        a
                    </div>
                    <div style="background-color:blue">
                        b
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="width:100px; background-color: yellow">
                    c
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now, the core-toolbar takes up some of the height, I need the "a" div to take up 60% of the rest of the height, the "b" div to take up the rest and the "c" div to take up the sum of the height of "a" and "b". I have tried lots of different combinations hoping that I would eventually understand and master it, but I need a push in the right direction. Can anyone help?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Now that I look at it in here, I can see that at least one of the divs does not make sense, but I doubt removing it is part of the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Updated answer

- Set the height to 100%.
- Add 'flex' to div a & b.

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/ea15f0vk/17/)

### Code

```
<body fullbleed unresolved>
  <div layout vertical style="height: 100%; width:100%;">
    <core-toolbar>
      <div>Help Me</div>
    </core-toolbar>
    <div horizontal layout flex>
      <div layout vertical flex>
        <div flex style="background-color:red">
          a
        </div>
        <div flex style="background-color:blue">
          b
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 100px; background-color: yellow">
        c
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested here: http://jsfiddle.net/ea15f0vk/. But it does not fill the browser window. Also, it seems that the a+b div will fill two thirds of the width, but in my original attempt it is set to 100px, which was intentional leaving the a+b div to fill the rest. The main issue is still the height. Any suggestions? Thanks for your effort :-)

Comment: Ok, sorry I miss understood, Do I update my existing answer or create a new one?